# Why does my Intel i5 (480M) only shows one core, two threads on Windows 8 RP? 

Tags: cpu, windows-8-preview

I've only had Windows 8 RP on my notebook for 2 days now, there are many things, such as Hyper-V, that works on it.

The notebook (MSI FX603-064US) has performed well with Windows 7 Pro x64 since buying in in 04/11. Just bought a new 128GB Crucial M4 SSD, to dual boot Win 7 & 8 Pro in October.

My question, on my i5 CPU, which has & shows as 2 cores, 4 threads on Win 7, only shows one core, 2 threads, & virtualization isn't enabled, though Hyper-V is on & ready to run, just haven't created a VM yet.

I've tried updating the chipset, to no avail. Anyone have any suggestions here?

Comment: How do you see how many cores/threads there are under Windows?  AFAIK you could only see this from the Task Manager, which only shows the number of cores (under CPU Usage History).  I'm just curious as to where you obtained those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as well with Windows 7 Ultimate, the way I fixed mine was to go to *Start → Run →*, type `msconfig`, Click on the *Boot tab → Advanced options*, uncheck the box where it says *Number of Processors* - it should be greyed out now. Click OK. Then restart computer and run CPU-Z or Windows Experience Index and your sub score should spike. My CPU was a subscore of 4.8 and now is 6.9 after enabling the second core.